# How to filtered Lookup Field in NewForm?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with Lookup field. In Newform, i want  filter Lookup field.

I use SPD, and created a new NewForm, then i deleted Lookup field and add a new dropdown list but i don't know how to add a datasource for it?

I don't want use SPServices.

How to filterd lookup field?

**Edit:**

look at the jQuery library for SharePoint, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

I use this code :)

```
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({
relationshipList: "Countries",
relationshipListColumn: "Title",
columnName: "Country",
CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>",
completefunc: null,
debug: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several projects for this on CodePlex, they are usually called **Cascading Dropdowns** and even got their own [tag on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=cascading%20dropdown)